# Tesseract giving diffrent results for the same image when "tessedit_char_whitelist" is set and ocr is done

Tags: c#, tesseract, tessnet2

I am using tesseract to find text in scanned image,

I am trying to set "tessedit_char_whitelist" by calling as follows, so that only alphanumeric search is performed

tes_obj.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

When I try to compare results between multiple searches on the same image, I found different results. What might be the reason for different results.

Regards,
Amrut

Comment: Please improve your question

Comment: If I compare result set returned on DoOCR API function call, the result sets are diffrent.